# How to close file objects when downloading files over FTP using Twisted?

Tags: python, ftp, twisted, ioerror

I've got the following code:

```
for f in fileListProtocol.files:
    if f['filetype'] == '-':
        filename = os.path.join(directory['filename'], f['filename'])
        print 'Downloading %s...' % (filename)
        newFile = open(filename, 'w+')
        d = ftpClient.retrieveFile(filename, FileConsumer(newFile))
        d.addCallback(closeFile, newFile)
```

Unfortunately, after downloading several hundred of the 1000+ files in the directory in question I get an IOError about too many open files. Why is this when I should be closing each file after they've been downloaded? If there's a more idiomatic way to approach the whole task of downloading lots of files too, I'd love to hear it. Thanks.

**Update:** Jean-Paul's `DeferredSemaphore` example plus Matt's `FTPFile` did the trick. For some reason using a `Cooperator` instead of `DeferredSemaphore` would download a few files and then fail because the FTP connection would have died.

Comment: The `FTPClient` serializes the commands, you shouldn't need either of JP's parallelization techniques. The problem was that your `FileConsumer` s ate file handles when instantiated AND they weren't closing the files when the download finished, I expect your `d.addCallback(closeFile, newFile)` wasn't working as intended. The class I provided only opens the file when needed and closes it when finished as it is supporting the protocol interface in the way that `retrieveFile` is expecting it to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you're using `FTPClient` from `twisted.protocols.ftp`... and I certainly hesitate before contradicting JP..

It seems that the `FileConsumer` class you're passing to `retrieveFile` will be adapted to `IProtocol` by `twisted.internet.protocol.ConsumerToProtocolAdapter`, which doesn't call `unregisterProducer`, so `FileConsumer` doesn't close the file object.

I've knocked up a quick protocol that you can use to receive the files. I think it should only open the file when appropriate. Totally untested, you'd use it in place of `FileConsumer` in your code above and won't need the `addCallback`.

```
from twisted.python import log
from twisted.internet import interfaces
from zope.interface import implements

class FTPFile(object):
    """
    A consumer for FTP input that writes data to a file.

    @ivar filename: a filename to be opened for writing.
    """

    implements(interfaces.IProtocol)

    def __init__(self, filename):
        self.fObj = None
        self.filename = filename

    def makeConnection(self,transport)
        self.fObj = open(self.filename,'wb')
        log.info('Opened %s for writing' % self.filename)

    def connectionLost(self,reason):
        self.fObj.close()
        log.info('Closed %s' % self.filename)

    def dataReceived(self, bytes):
        self.fObj.write(bytes)
```

Comment: I don't see a contradiction here. :)  Opening the files just in time makes sense if `FTPClient` is already serializing the operations.  You'd still need to be careful if you're connecting to many different FTP servers though (or even if you're opening many different connections to a single FTP server).

Answer (score 1):

You're opening every file in `fileListProtocol.files` simultaneously, downloading contents to them, and then closing each when each download is complete.  So, you have `len(fileListProtocol.files)` files open at the beginning of the process.  If there are too many files in that list, then you'll try to open too many files.

You probably want to limit yourself to some fairly small number of parallel downloads at once (if FTP even supports parallel downloads, which I'm not entirely certain is the case).

http://jcalderone.livejournal.com/24285.html and [Queue remote calls to a Python Twisted perspective broker?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2861858/queue-remote-calls-to-a-python-twisted-perspective-broker) may be of some help in figuring out how to limit the number of downloads you start in parallel.

Comment: From looking at `FTPClientBasic` I was under the impression that it queued commands.

Comment: I had no idea that I was opening every file but now that I think about it that makes sense. Naturally I want to only have a few open. I'll look into your links.

Comment: Jean-Paul, I tried to use your Cooperator code, which looks like exactly what I need, but unfortunately got the exact same problem. Would you say that the `work` iterator in `parallel` is opening all files simultaneously still? Do I need Matt's code also?

Comment: It's hard to say without seeing all of the actual code.  Matt's version has the advantage of only opening files when the server is ready to send them to you.  This is cool, but it shouldn't strictly be necessary as long as you're keeping the total number of outstanding requests below the open file limit (minus some for however many random other files (and sockets!) you have open).